# How can this code generate a file with a filename containing a colon on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, pascal, internal, computer-forensics

I see the pascal code below on another forum. How can this code be possible?

Doesn't windows allow user to create a filename with colon?

However, this code only work when you create a file with name contains colon in root directory of drive (Ex: D:, C:, E:, etc). And when the file is created, it's completely invisible.

```
uses crt, sysutils;
var
  f, f1: file of char;
  c:char;
begin
  clrscr;
  assign(f, 'D:\src\payload.exe');
  reset(f);
  assign(f1, 'D:\:malware.exe');
  rewrite(f1);
  while not eof(f) do
  begin
    read(f, c);
    write(f1, c);
  end;
  close(f1);
  close(f);
  executeprocess('D:\:malware.exe', ''); //here
  readln;
  erase(f1);
end.
```

You can compile the code above with free pascal

```
fpc [filename].pas
```

Thank you.

EDIT:

For more detail:

You can execute `D:\:malware.exe` from CreateProcess (WinAPI)

You can't execute `D:\:malware.exe` from command line, path, etc

I use process explorer to find `D:\:malware.exe` path/contain folder. However, when I pressed explore button, it takes me to %UserProfile%

It only work for `D:\:malware.exe`, `D:\\malware.exe`, `D:\/malware.exe`

Comment: Colon is reserved in the file-system namespace for file systems that support named streams, such as NTFS [file streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364404). The colon *is not* part of the base filename. It delimits the base name from the stream name. You're creating a $DATA stream named "malware.exe" on the root directory. Even directories can have $DATA streams, but unlike regular files they can't have a default anonymous $DATA stream (e.g. opening "file.ext" is really opening its anonymous "file.ext::$DATA" file stream).

Comment: Similarly, the file listing of a directory is stored in an $INDEX_ALLOCATION stream, which is normally named $I30. So if both the file system and the API you're using support stream names, then you can referenced the root directory contents as "D:\:$I30:$INDEX_ALLOCATION".

Comment: Device names (e.g. "C:") are in the NT object namespace, not the file-system namespace, so they can consist of any Unicode characters except the path separator, backslash. Forward slash is just a name character in the object namespace. New device names can be added via `DefineDosDevice` and accessed with either the "\\.\" or "\\?\" prefix. The "\\.\" prefix still entails some path normalization of slash and dot characters, but "\\?\" bypasses all normalization.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much.

By the way, can you recommend some books or keyword to learn about this?

Comment: Read [Alternate Data Streams in NTFS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs). To delve a bit deeper, read: [The Four Stages of NTFS File Growth](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2009/10/16/the-four-stages-of-ntfs-file-growth), [NTFS MetaFiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2009/12/30/ntfs-metafiles/), and [NTFS File Attributes](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/08/25/ntfs-file-attributes/). Beyond that, you'll need to search for articles on forensic analysis of NTFS. That's not my cup of tea.

Answer (score 0):

It works because it is possible*. You can name files all kinds of horrid things, regardless of proper naming convention.

*Yes, I know [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) lists colons as *“reserved”*. That is not the same as forbidden or impossible. It is *only* the same as “don’t do it”.

Comment: How is it possible, though? This is a restriction on the win32 API. It's not so simple as "you can do it", but rather, *how* can you do it? For example, I just tried through standard Windows means (explorer, command prompt, Powershell) as well as Python to no avail.

Comment: I've tested with `>malware.exe`, `"malware.exe`, etc. However, only `:malware.exe` works in this example. I think `:malware.exe` is some kind of special system file. Especially, it only work at `D:\:malware.exe`, `C:\:malware.exe`, etc. `D:\sample_folder\:malware.exe` will throw an error.

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness, `D:\\malware.exe`, `D:\/malware.exe` will also work.

Comment: @Thebluefish I just tried it with Ruby (`irb` interactive environment) and I did not get an error in an attempt to create and write to a file named `:bar.txt`. I suspect some APIs don't properly check.

Comment: @Thebluefish I just tried Python 3.6 4 on Windows 10 at a command prompt. It let me open, write, and close a file named ":bar.txt".

Comment: @lurker it let me do that too, however I cannot execute the file, and loading a Linux Live CD indicates no such file was actually created.

Comment: @Thebluefish yes, same with me. No file is actually "visible". It just acts like it created it. I couldn't tell if there was a file there but simply not visible to the directory listing tools or what. The OP is claiming the `CreateProcess` API finds the file if it's an executable.

Comment: @lurker I just tried creating an "executable", named without the colon, executes as I expect - With the colon, acts like it created, write, closed, but could not find it when attempting to execute. I wonder (yet strongly doubt) if Pascal is using something besides the Win32 API to do the heavy lifting, but cannot check.

Comment: @Thebluefish I was thinking that too (Pascal is using an alternative to the Win32 API) but I would think latest Windows versions might not allow it - as in actual file system operations are protected OS operations (?).

Comment: If you are using Object Pascal or Delphi, you are, in fact, using the WinAPI to create the file names. If you are using something old and weird, then you might not be. Either way, verification of the file name is done in various places, and not all in the same way depending on the API and the OS version. You can _create_ the file. Many things will not like it.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I didn't think the "old and weird" approaches would work on newer versions of Windows. Maybe if run as an administrator it *might* allow it.